# Is non-local type inference in Haskell or OCaml really useful?

Tags: haskell, ocaml, type-inference

First, let us assume that local type inference is the sort of type inference found in Scala and C#. Scala local type inference is explained here: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/127

Also, let us assume, that a definition such as

```
     fact 0 = 1
     fact n = n * fact(n-1)
```

would count as local type inference -- that is, type inference here is local to function fact. Scala does not permit such a type inferece; still let us count it as local.

The question, then, is whether anyone has a practical example of at least 2 mutually-recursive functions (or any other non-locality at your discretion) that derive some benefit from type inference? Please do not post silly examples such as:

```
    odd 0 = false
    odd n = even(n-1)

    even 0 = true
    even n = odd(n-1)
```

I suspect that non-silly, practical examples arise in parses. Also, please could you explain the benefits a programmer could derive from such uses of non-local type inference?

UPDATE:

I appreciate any example of insufficiency of local type inference and the need for full-blown type inference.

1. Your Haskell or OCaml example may be 90% correct, because you are only 90% understand the term "non-local type inference". Still, you have to understand Haskell (or OCaml) type inference.
2. Your example may be written on Scala or C#. Please point out that compliler really has enough information to infer the type, but the type can not be inferred due to language specification or due to local-only nature of type inference in Scala or C#.

// And again, feel free to correct my english.

Comment: I am often annoyed by the _local-only_ nature of type inference in C#. For example, if I want to refactor a LINQ query into a function, I am often obligated to do a bunch of incidental coding (such as coming up with a one-off type to represent the query projection) to make that happen.

Comment: @DanielPratt could you give a more detailed example of such a situation? may be post a link to your blog article; I am interested in type inference in any language

Comment: This seems like an odd question. The benefits are the same as any other type inference, and having *only* local inference is a spurious limitation that gets in the way of refactoring, as Daniel Pratt says. Why do you need a specific example for "why to not cripple a useful feature"?

Comment: Some of the difference in perspective here could be accounted for by the fact that the distinction between non-local and local is much stronger in mainstream languages as it is in functional languages. In functional languages, you could very well have functions defined inside functions defined inside functions... (e.g. the JS module pattern?). Probably the reason why many languages require type annotations on functions is the same reason that there is a convention in functional languages of putting type signatures on top-level definitions. To be continued...

Comment: ...The problem (as it often is) is that mainstream languages conflate the idea of modularizing code into a function with putting that function at the top-level.

Comment: @C.A.McCann You probaly know that type inference is undecidable in some type systems. I'm sorry, but I shall not participate in global discussion like "type inference vs. type annotation". If you have an example of any annoying limitation of local type inference -- you are welcome to post it.

Comment: @user1123502: Yes, some language features make full type inference impossible, and in the presence of such features crippling type inference may be sensible. That doesn't explain why you want a reason to *not* place artificial limits on a useful feature. It's like asking "is it really useful to allow the letter Q in function names?".

Comment: Furthermore, the inference vs. annotation debate is irrelevant. Non-local type inference doesn't *forbid* you from using annotations, it just makes more of them optional.

Comment: @C.A.McCann It's like asking "is it really useful to allow Futhorc and Sanskrit characters in function names?". It may be usefull, but definitely it has drawbacks. And it is *you* who have to point out the benefits.

Comment: So... you just want an example of a pair of useful, mutually recursive functions? Would you consider that a good example of the usefulness of non-local type inference?

Comment: @user1123502: Your question was "is it useful", not "how useful is it relative to any drawbacks". If you think type inference is useful, you already know the benefits. I'm not sure what you're trying to ask here.

Comment: @C.A.McCann My question is "How usefull is full-blown type inference relative to local type inference". I know benefits of local type inference, but still do not know ADDITIONAL benefits of non-local one.

Comment: @user1123502: They're the same thing, so the benefits are the same.

Comment: @C.A.McCann Do you think my original post needs clarifcation? What about such a title as "How usefull is full-blown type inference relative to local type inference"?

Comment: @C.A.McCann They may be same thing form the perspective of theorist or even compiler writer. They are definitely not the same thing from the perspective of application programmer, for example, because human may not keep in mind enough non-local information to calculate precise non-locally infered type. I do not want to say that human always need to calculate precise non-locally infered type. But in such a case when he is really need to calculate it in mind the distinction is critical.

Comment: @user1123502: Yes, which is one reason that using type annotations is good practice even in cases where they're not required. But the programmer's idea of what's "local enough" is unlikely to match the language's idea of what's local, so why not let the programmer choose?

Comment: From applying functors, highly recursive functions, and dealing with complex sets of arguments, from three lines of code to three thousand it is helpful. I would really like to see an example where it ISN'T helpful. Furthermore, I really don't see a distinction of "local" and "non-local". Once you break out of "local" functions scope, your going to be in "local" modules, "local" module packs, "local" libraries...

Comment: @nlucaroni OK, you would really like to see an example where it ISN'T helpful. Does it mean that you can easily post a bunch of different examples when non-local type inference is helpful? If so, please post.

Comment: @C.A.McCann Your question "why not let the programmer choose?" may be relevant for language design decision, but is irrelevant to the topic. Nevertheless, short answer: any programmer's choice need information. For example, such information as "I am decided to restrict himself to local inferece only; what am I losing?".

Comment: First, I think you should specify exactly what you mean by local type inference, otherwise it's hard to tell you when it's convenient to have more.

Comment: @augustss If you **think** that some type inference is non-local and usefull in practice -- please post it.

Comment: @user1123502 Well, the reason I ask what you mean is that according to the standard definition of local type inference your fact function cannot be given a type.

Comment: @augustss Please give me a link to standard definition of local type inference. Also, I shall not insist on my definition. Instead, one may reformulate my question like this: "Please give a usefull example of non-local inference. Note, that I am aware of such inference as in fact function, so please give another example."

Comment: @user1123502 So, I'd say that any inference of a type of a (recursive) function where you don't give the types of arguments and return type is non-local, but the exact definition of non-local is not totally nailed down, IMO.  I think the standard reference is Pierce&Turner, http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&ved=0CGYQFjAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.105.833%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=jmT_TonBO4mF4gTT4cGdAQ&usg=AFQjCNFdkcqKveaFZJTJbGudzUABvoxw0g

Comment: @user1123502 I don't see why my mention of functor application isn't a decent example.

Comment: @nlucaroni Please post a little code example, not necessary a practical or real. These comments permit to post code.

Comment: @augustss I consider fact definition as a syntactic sugar over such definition as `fact n = if n > 0 then n * fact(n-1) else 1` According to your link, "Both methods [of inference] are local in the sense that missing annotations are recovered using only information from adjacent nodes in the syntax tree, without long-distance constraints such as uniﬁcation variables." I still do not read it, but it seems to me that short distance uniﬁcation variables are local from the point of view of practical programmer.

Comment: @user1123502 If the type of `n` and `fact` are not known when type checking the body of `fact` you will need 'long-distance unification'.  Otherwise, what would you do with `n > 0` and the constraints that entails and then combining that with the `n-1` constraints.

Comment: @aug Let us consider Scala line `var x = some_function(123)`. Although some_function may be defined very long from this line, inference is considered local. So, mere use of some non-local type information does not make inference to be non-local. Let us name such long-distance contraints to be trivial. At the other hand, let us consider mutually recursive functions, like `even` and `odd` from my post. Suppose, `even` and `odd` definitions are separated by 1000 lines of code due to some real reason and not due to whim of a programmer. So, here is long-distance non-trivial constraints.

Comment: Sure, but the type of `some_function` is know everywhere so no unification is needed.  In `fact` the type of `n` is not known, which is why unification (or similar non-local reasoning) is needed.  Basically, the type of all free variables in an expression need to be known to do local type inference.

Comment: My simplified definition of local type inference is that the type of all atomic expressions must be known, and the type of a compound expression can be deduced by just looking at the immediate subexpressions.  You can relax this a bit if operating in checking rather than deduction mode.

Comment: @augustss I do understand, that `n-1` need to be analized to point out that it merely uses some non-local type information, or, equivalently, has only trivial non-local constraints.

Comment: @augustss My point is that type inference of `n` may be made local by carefull language specification, even though it may be non-local in current haskell specification.

Comment: @augustss My supposed definition is slightly broader than yours. It's enough to analyse `fact`'s body (and may be make unification) to find `fact`'s type. At the other hand, to find `even` type, you need to analyze body of another function `odd` AND to satisfy long-distance constrant(s).

Comment: @user1123502 Sounds like you have your own definition of 'local type inference', which is why I asked what you meant in the first place.  So what's non-local to you?  Between different functions?  What about between different local functions within a global function?

Comment: @augustss Let us consider scala-like definition `var x = 2.5 - 1/x`, where both `x` name **the same** variable. It's obvious, that inference it local. However, one may need to solve local constraints, and analogically, one need to find the root of such a local equation. Type of `n` in `fact n = if n > 0 then n * fact(n-1) else 1` also can be infered locally. Different local functions within a global function have to be considered different functions. There may be compiler directive to treat their inferences as local (and a similar directive for module, for example).

Comment: @augustss **CORRECTION** However, one may need to solve local type constraints, and analogically, one need to find the root of such a local numeric equation.

Comment: The `var x = 2.5 - 1/x` example is not local inference in the standard sense since it uses information that is not from the adjacent parse tree nodes, nor is know.  The type of `x` is inferred by unification at an arbitrary distance.

Comment: @augustss I appreciate current terminology, but my perspective is slightly different. Not local? If so, please demonstrate what is a non-local **use** of `x` that may change infered `x` type. Redefinition of `-` operator, for example, is not allowed for your demonstration, because it is trivial constraint. Anyway, even if such a demonstration may exist, it has to be disabled by language definition.

Comment: Why should I make such a demonstration?  Just because the type is unique doesn't mean inference is local.  Non-local inference also give you a unique type.

Comment: @augustss Why? Because you said "The type of x is inferred by unification at an arbitrary distance". So, I disagree, and I want an example of "arbitrary distance" that really affects infered type of x. Do you think that Scal-ish example is not appropiate? Then let us agree on haskell example rules. Say, example has to be like this: `fact n = some combination of precisely typed functions u, v, w..., and fact, and n`; "`u` is precisely typed" means "`u` has explicitly written signature `u :: ...`" or any other similar meaning that **you** find to be appropriate.

Comment: @augustss Let us rename `fact` form the above comment to `fact1`.

Comment: @augustss Then, the questions are: 1. Is there fact1 usage that can affect fact1 infered type? If so, then inference is non-local just for me.  2. Is there such a "`u` is precisely typed" definition above, that any fact1 usage can not affect fact1 infered type? // BTW, it seems possible that with your valuable help I shall find precise wording for the next SO question.

Comment: @augustss As for me, the `toResult` is not precisely typed: `class Result a where toResult :: String -> a`. Although the technique is interesting and usefull, it seems to be easily replaceable by implicit conversions. Then it is possible to restrict programmer to precisely typed functions, explicitly separated from implicit converstions. After that it is possible to remove unwanted behavior from such a local type inference as in `fact n = if n > 0 then n * fact(n-1) else 1` ... or not possible? I still belive that your definition of local type inference 1) correct 2) too conservative.

Comment: @C.A.McCann I was trying to minimize discussion in comments while my question was open. Now my question is closed, so I can give much elaborated feedback to your question "why not let the programmer choose?", if you want. Anyway, any choice of programmer must be supported by compiler. This includes support not only for any individual choice to annotate type of any individual function, but also support for "generic" choice to type-annotate all the functions of, say, a module. In such a setting compiler has at least to warn programmer when programmer is violating his generic choice.

Comment: @user1123502 You need to explain what you mean by local type inference, it's not what Scala calls local type inference.  Until you explain that I will stop arguing with you (and saying, assume ... can be done using local inference is not enough).  In Scala you have to write `def fact(n:Int):Int = if ...` and that can be checked using local inference, because the types of `n` and `fact` are known in the body of `fact`.  If the type annotations are left out it is no longer local inference according to the normal definition of the term.

Comment: @augustss This SO question, answer and discussion is a good starting point. I shall probably split my question into series of little, more precise ones and post them probably on stackexange. Also I need some time to read some related pdf-s.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what examples would count for you, because you mention both non-locality and mutual recursion, and I don't understand whether an example that exhibits just non-locality is enough.

I will say that a common technique in Haskell is to write functions whose return type is a class-constrained type variable not mentioned in the argument types.  For example, like this:

```hs
foo :: (Result a) => String -> a
foo = toResult . transform  -- transform :: String -> String

class Result a where
   toResult :: String -> a

-- Example implementation of Result class—with this, callers that 
-- expect foo to return an Integer will get the length of the result
-- of transform.
instance Result Integer where
   toResult = length
```

In this case, the concrete type of the result of any call to `foo` is determined by type inference at the calling site.  I.e., the return type of any call to `foo` is inferred from information not present in the definition of `foo`.

One practical example of this is Haskell's regular expression libraries.  The interface uses this pattern so that, instead of having a bunch of different regexp matching functions that return different types, there is a regexp matching operator that is polymorphic on the return type as shown above, and thus the caller's type inference controls what is returned.

So for example, if you do regexp matching in a calling context where the inferred return type is an integer, you get back number of matches.  If the calling context expects a boolean, you get True if there were any matches.  If the calling context expects a list of strings, you get a list of the substrings that matched the regexp.  A bunch of other return type-specific behaviors are defined—and you can define your own for arbitrary return types by implementing your own instances of the library's type class for results.

Answer (score 3):

FFS what do you want? The odd/even example is good. Just use your imagination. Do you really want me to post 5502 lines of mutually recursive Ocaml functions used flx_lookup.ml, used in my Felix compiler? [I'd give a link but the webserver is crashing at the moment;[

```
let rec trclose state bsym_table rs sr fs = ...
and resolve_inherits state bsym_table rs sr x = ...
and inner_lookup_name_in_env state bsym_table env rs sr name 
 : entry_set_t = ...
and lookup_qn_in_env2'
  state
 (bsym_table:Flx_bsym_table.t)
 (env:env_t)
  (rs:recstop)
  (qn: qualified_name_t)
  : entry_set_t * typecode_t list
= ...
and lookup_qn_in_env'
  (state:lookup_state_t)
  bsym_table
  (env:env_t) rs
  (qn: qualified_name_t)
  : entry_kind_t * typecode_t list
= ...
and inner_bind_type state (bsym_table:Flx_bsym_table.t) env sr rs t = ...
... lots more ...
```

You'll notice the annotations on some of the arguments, that's because type inference sucks when it comes to finding type errors in precisely the circumstances you're asking for a benefit. The annotations constrain the inference enough to help the compiler bug out on the line actually containing the bug. Ocaml compiler is not smart enough to trace how it infers types when a conflict is detected: this is a downside of inference (tracing the source of the inference is essential for reporting type errors, but it would seem to be very hard and it isn't clear that even if the information were available it could be reported in a suitable way).

I personally dislike inference, particularly as it has some very bad properties: it doesn't work properly in Ocaml in the presence of polymorphic variants, is hard to extend to support overloading, is hard to extend to support polymorphic recursion, and doesn't necessarily terminate. It makes code hard to read because types are not named and the reader has to effectively duplicate the inference process in their head.

The upside is it makes code look cleaner. After adding type annotations to find bugs, on finding the bug I often remove the annotations.

If you compare Ocaml function definitions with those in Felix, which does not provide inference, you will immediately see the Felix code is a lot more verbose. However inference really shines when refactoring. It makes it so easy.

Comment: I do not see a website in your profile; what is the url of your felix compiler?